# Dynamic meta title not showing in view page source Angular Universal

Tags: angular, seo, angular-universal

When I am updating meta title by api response , its not updating in view page source.

```
this.httpService.getBlogsDetails(Id).subscribe((response: any) => {
  this.blogDetails = response?.data?.blog;
  this.htmlPart = this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(response?.data?.blog?.description);
  this.spinner.hide();

  this.titleService.setTitle(response?.data?.blog?.meta_title);

  this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'robots', content: "Index,Follow" });
  this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'title', content: response?.data?.blog?.meta_title });
  this.metaService.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: response?.data?.blog?.meta_description });


}
```

Comment: Need more information. During, ng serve, the meta title will not be added to the view page source. Have you tried to build your app and run it, and check if the meta title is dispalyed ?

Comment: yes I tried to build and run but still , meta title not displaying in page source

Comment: actully I am getting meta title from api and when I am putting that api response into meta setTitle its's not displaying into page source

Comment: You should share your code.

Comment: I shared by code , above

Comment: When you open the code source page, do you have the application correctly rendering with angular universal ? Or, do you have "<app-root></app-root>" with noting inside ?

Comment: yes application running in uiversal

Comment: Can you share your view page source ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try not to use web requests during SSR, but pass data from the backend to the angular app through the bootmodule ([More information](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Routing/blob/master/Demo/Demo.Web/ClientApp/src/main.server.ts))

Comment: Also I created a [.NET template](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates/tree/master/src/content/ServerSideRendering) with the code ready, where [`OnSupplyData`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates/blob/master/src/content/ServerSideRendering/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.ServerSideRendering/Services/SpaPrerenderingService.cs#L33) is implemented. You can instal them with [these instructions](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.Templates#installing-the-templates)

Comment: This comment suggested using `addTag()` instead of updateTag()` - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43442#issuecomment-919478695

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should provide information what is in your server.ts configuration.

You have to remember that Angular Universal and express engine is not a browser based so some of browser objects like **window, document** etc. **are not available**, you can find it in angular docs:

> Because a Universal app doesn't execute in the browser, some of the browser APIs and capabilities may be missing on the server.

And all the Meta methods for tags are based on document object.

You have to be sure that you provide some abstraction for this operation (document injection or some other tool like **Domino** package which provides support for the DOM API on SSR.

Comment: is there any resource for more info about this answer? @tmkd